# Active Admin Login slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin

I'm using active admin in my rails 3.0.9 app with the default setup.i.e I have `User` model with devise authentication for customer login and Active Admin is running on `AdminUser` model. All Ok apart from the active admin login page. When I try to access http://localhost:3000/admin I get the active admin login page very quickly. But after I enter the username/password correctly/incorrectly the authentication process takes nearly 3-5 minutes. Because of this reason I can't even deploy the app on heroku, and I get timeout errors on heroku logs.

But how ever in development mode after I logged in to active admin, everything works perfectly. I'm assuming this is happening due an issue with routing. So I'm pasting my routes file here with fully.

http://pastie.org/3153643

Can some one help me on this please? Thanks

**UPDATE 09-Jan:** Its seems like the issue is not related to the routes I think. I removed all the other models/controllers/views/routes leaving only `User` and `AdminUser` stuffs. But I still experiencing the slowness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind I've found the issue and the probably the solution as well. I'm posting it here so it will help someone else with a similar issue.

In my application I was originally using `authlogic` gem for authentication but recently I've switched over this to `devise` for better support. But I still wanted to allow old users to login to the app with same passwords. So I've overridden the devise encryption from Bcrypt to Authlogic's sha512 as below.

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.encryptor = :authlogic_sha512
```

But I never change the `AdminUser` model to fit with the above change.

So the fix should be in my model I should use the `:encryptable` and `:encryptor => :authlogic_sha512`

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:encryptable, `:encryptor => :authlogic_sha512`

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

And in  AdminUser migration file encryptable columns should be enabled

```
create_table(:admin_users) do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable

      t.encryptable
      # t.confirmable
      # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
      # t.token_authenticatable


      t.timestamps
    end
```